# How do I mock multiple levels of DbSet.Include lambdas?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I'm using Moq to write unit tests that use Entity Framework 6 `DbSet` and `DbContext` objects.  I have a service method with a cascading/multi-level `Include` and I can't figure out how to set it up for testing.  The service method looks something like this:

```
return DataContext.Cars
    .Include(p => p.Model)
    .Include(p => p.Model.Make)
    .Select(c => new 
         {
             Key = c.CarId, 
             Value = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", c.Model.Make.Name, c.Model.Name, c.Trim)
         }
    ).ToArray();
```

I know that I have to setup the `Include` to return the mocked object, like this:

```
mockCarDbSet.Setup(m => m.Include(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(mockCarSet.Object);
```

But I'm getting a null reference exception from the cascaded `.Include(p => p.Model.Make)`.  How do I set up Moq to handle multiple levels of `Include`?

**EDIT**
OK, so it turns out that I can't use `It.IsAny<string>` for `Include` calls that use lambdas instead of strings, so now I have two problems:

1. How do I setup a mock with Include that accepts a lambda?
2. Will the setup for above cascade to multiple levels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to @Old Fox reminding me that Moq won't work with static members, I found a way to do this using Microsoft Fakes.  Shims allows you to shim static methods.  I used Moq to set up `Mock<DbSet>` objects for each of the entities:

```
var carData = new List<Car>{new Car{ Trim = "Whatever" }};  
var mockCarSet = new Mock<DbSet<Car>>();
mockCarSet.As<IQueryable<Car>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(carData.Provider);
mockCarSet.As<IQueryable<Car>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(carData.Expression);
mockCarSet.As<IQueryable<Car>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(carData.ElementType);
mockCarSet.As<IQueryable<Car>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(carData.GetEnumerator);
var mockMakeSet = new Mock<DbSet<Make>>();
//do the same stuff as with Car for IQueryable Setup
var mockModelSet = new Mock<DbSet<Model>>();
//do the same stuff as with Car for IQueryable Setup
using(ShimsContext.Create())
{
    //hack to return the first, since this is all mock data anyway
    ShimModel.AllInstances.MakeGet = model => mockMakeSet.Object.First();
    ShimCar.AllInstances.ModelGet = car => mockModelSet.Object.First();
    //run the test
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`include()` is a static method(extension method).
`Moq` doesn't support a static methods mock([read this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562129/how-do-i-use-moq-to-mock-an-extension-method)).

To test your code you need to set your `mockCarDbSet` to return `IQueryable<Car>`:

```
var carQuery = new List<Car>
{
    //add cars
}
IQueryable<Post> query = carQuery.AsQueryable();
```

return `query` as a result of `DataContext.Cars`

Those steps will work around the static method problem.

Comment: Actually, Moq handles .Include(It.IsAny<string>) just fine, which works great against DbSet.Include("SomeEntity").  See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21979183/27457

Comment: The example in the link use the object method. This method gets a string as a parameter([the link method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696717%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)). In your code, you use the extension method.

Comment: The slight issue here is that the first use if Include(...), is the method of the DbSet<T> (which can be mocked) that then returns an IQueryable<T>.  The second call is therefore performed using the static Include(...) extension method for IQueryable<T>.

Comment: @Phil , ammm... I think you should go over again on the OP code... as I wrote to the OP, a work around is to set the `DataContext.Cars` to return a list of cars.... BTW 3 months later I posted [this answer to the question: How to write this EF Mock setup code as a reusable Generic Boilerplate?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33641349/4332059)(which is relevant to this question...)

Comment: @Old Fox. Thanks for the advice.  It's just I've found that that answer only works when the Include method of DbSet is used, but not for the QueryableExtensions.Include method.

Comment: @Phil you welcome, actually this answer won't work when the Include method of DbSet is used... The problem that the OP faced was that; he did the correct setup for the Include method of DbSet and then null reference raised...